# JNI returns different jobjects for the same logical Java object

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I need to obtain the current thread, but the java object Thread, not the windows kernel GetCurrentThread().
But i have this problem:
code:

```
void MyTest(JNIEnv* env) {
    jobject t1 = GetJavaCurrentThread(env);
    jobject t2 = GetJavaCurrentThread(env);

    if (t1 != t2) {
        std::cout << "this shouldn't happen. some informations:" << endl;
        std::cout << t1 << " " << t2 << endl;
        std::cout << GetJavaThreadName(env, t1) << " " << GetJavaThreadName(env, t2) << endl;
    }
}

jobject GetJavaCurrentThread(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass threadClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");
    jmethodID currentThreadMtd = env->GetStaticMethodID(threadClass, "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;");
    return env->CallStaticObjectMethod(threadClass, currentThreadMtd);
}

const char* GetJavaThreadName(JNIEnv* env, jobject thread) {
    jclass threadClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Thread");
    jmethodID getNameMtd = env->GetMethodID(threadClass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring name = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(thread, getNameMtd);
    return env->GetStringUTFChars(name, NULL);
}
```

logs:
[image]

why do i get different objects from calling Thread.currentThread from jni ?

Maybe this is the wrong to way to obtain the java-side Thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JNI specification has this to say on the topic of local references, which is what you get back from functions like `CallStaticObjectMethod`:

> To implement local references, the Java VM creates a registry for each transition of control from Java to a native method. A registry maps nonmovable local references to Java objects, and keeps the objects from being garbage collected. All Java objects passed to the native method (including those that are returned as the results of JNI function calls) are automatically added to the registry. The registry is deleted after the native method returns, allowing all of its entries to be garbage collected.
>
> There are different ways to implement a registry, such as using a table, a linked list, or a hash table. **Although reference counting may be used to avoid duplicated entries in the registry, a JNI implementation is not obliged to detect and collapse duplicate entries.**

This means that the implementation is allowed to give you two separate local references to the same Thread object.
If you want to test object equality, use the [JNI IsSameObject method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16514):

```
jboolean areEqual = env->IsSameObject(t1, t2);
```